# Make apache storm topology to use latest offset from kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I have a kafkaspout, 2 bolts to process data, 2 bolts to store processed data in mongodb

I am using apache flux to create topology where I am reading data into spout from kafka. Everything is running fine but every time I run the topology, it processes all the msgs in kafka from the start. 
and once it processes all the msgs, it does not wait for more msgs and crashes.

[image: Error Message]

**How can I make storm topology to process latest msgs only.**

here is my topology file .yaml

```
name: "kafka-topology"

components:
# MongoDB mapper
  - id: "block-mapper"
    className: "org.apache.storm.mongodb.common.mapper.SimpleMongoMapper"
    configMethods:
      - name: "withFields"
        args: # The following are the tuple fields to map to a MongoDB document
          - ["block"]
# MongoDB mapper
  - id: "transaction-mapper"
    className: "org.apache.storm.mongodb.common.mapper.SimpleMongoMapper"
    configMethods:
      - name: "withFields"
        args: # The following are the tuple fields to map to a MongoDB document
          - ["transaction"]

  - id: "stringScheme"
    className: "org.apache.storm.kafka.StringScheme"

  - id: "stringMultiScheme"
    className: "org.apache.storm.spout.SchemeAsMultiScheme"
    constructorArgs:
      - ref: "stringScheme"

  - id: "zkHosts"
    className: "org.apache.storm.kafka.ZkHosts"
    constructorArgs:
      - "172.25.33.191:2181"

  - id: "spoutConfig"
    className: "org.apache.storm.kafka.SpoutConfig"
    constructorArgs:
      # brokerHosts
      - ref: "zkHosts"
      # topic
      - "blockdata"
      # zkRoot
      - ""
      # id
      - "myId"
    properties:
      - name: "scheme"
        ref: "stringMultiScheme"
      - name: "ignoreZkOffsets"
        value: flase



config:
  topology.workers: 1
  # ...

# spout definitions
spouts:
  - id: "kafka-spout"
    className: "org.apache.storm.kafka.KafkaSpout"
    constructorArgs:
      - ref: "spoutConfig"
    parallelism: 1

# bolt definitions
bolts:
  - id: "blockprocessing-bolt"
    className: "org.apache.storm.flux.wrappers.bolts.FluxShellBolt"
    constructorArgs:
      # command line
      - ["python", "process-bolt.py"]
      # output fields
      - ["block"]
    parallelism: 1
    # ...
  - id: "transprocessing-bolt"
    className: "org.apache.storm.flux.wrappers.bolts.FluxShellBolt"
    constructorArgs:
      # command line
      - ["python", "trans-bolt.py"]
      # output fields
      - ["transaction"]
    parallelism: 1
    # ...

  - id: "mongoBlock-bolt"
    className: "org.apache.storm.mongodb.bolt.MongoInsertBolt"
    constructorArgs:
      - "mongodb://172.25.33.205:27017/testdb"
      - "block"
      - ref: "block-mapper"
    parallelism: 1
    # ...

  - id: "mongoTrans-bolt"
    className: "org.apache.storm.mongodb.bolt.MongoInsertBolt"
    constructorArgs:
      - "mongodb://172.25.33.205:27017/testdb"
      - "transaction"
      - ref: "transaction-mapper"
    parallelism: 1
    # ...



  - id: "log"
    className: "org.apache.storm.flux.wrappers.bolts.LogInfoBolt"
    parallelism: 1
    # ...

#stream definitions
# stream definitions define connections between spouts and bolts.
# note that such connections can be cyclical
# custom stream groupings are also supported

streams:


  - name: "kafka --> block-Processing" # name isn't used (placeholder for logging, UI, etc.)
    from: "kafka-spout"
    to: "blockprocessing-bolt"
    grouping:
      type: SHUFFLE

  - name: "kafka --> transaction-processing" # name isn't used (placeholder for logging, UI, etc.)
    from: "kafka-spout"
    to: "transprocessing-bolt"
    grouping:
      type: SHUFFLE

  - name: "block --> mongo"
    from: "blockprocessing-bolt"
    to: "mongoBlock-bolt"
    grouping:
      type: SHUFFLE

  - name: "transaction --> mongo"
    from: "transprocessing-bolt"
    to: "mongoTrans-bolt"
    grouping:
      type: SHUFFLE
```

I have tried adding property to spoutconfig for fetching latest msgs only like this

```
 - id: "spoutConfig"
className: "org.apache.storm.kafka.SpoutConfig"
constructorArgs:
  - ref: "zkHosts"
  - "blockdata"
  - ""
  - "myId"
properties:
  - name: "scheme"
    ref: "stringMultiScheme"
  - name: "startOffsetTime"
    ref: "EarliestTime"

  - name: "forceFromStart"
    value: false
```

But It gives **error no matter what I place in ref of startOffsetTime**

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set long field org.apache.storm.kafka.KafkaConfig.startOffsetTime to null value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the startOffsetTime to kafka.api.OffsetRequest.LatestTime. As you can see at https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/64af629a19a82591dbf3428f7fd6b02f39e0723f/external/storm-kafka#kafkaconfig, the default setting will go to the earliest offset available.

The exception you're hitting seems unrelated. It looks like a Curator/Zookeeper incompatibility.

Edit: I think you're hitting this issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-2978. 1.2.2 should be out soon, please try upgrading once it releases.

Edit edit: If you want to work around it without upgrading, edit the pom for your topology so it includes a dependency on Zookeeper 3.4 and not 3.5.

Comment: Thank you Stig. I am creating topology using yaml file, how do I set startOffsetTime to kafka.api.OffsetRequest.LatestTime in yaml file?  I have searched it for hours but cant get around it.

Comment: I have made an edit about spoutConfig where I am unable to set startOffsetTime property in yaml topology. Please see the updated
Really appreciate your help :)